# How to make sure the query run with read-only action on MySQL/PostgreSQL database?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, postgresql

**Precondition**: The database is running at somewhere without of my control, but I have the authorization account to connect the database.

I need to make sure all queries running through my application connection to database should be read-only. Such as SELECT in DML.

Using regex to judge the SQL query?
Is there any reusable Function/Class in SQLAlchemy or other Python packages?

Any suggestion will be helpful! Thanks!

Comment: In Postgresql [`BEGIN READ ONLY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-begin.html).

Comment: @iljaeverilä  Thanks! I see, do some tricks around user SQL. I found the `START TRANSACTION READ ONLY` for MySQL. Thanks!

Comment: Np. The reason parsing the query with regex etc. and checking if it contains DML or such would ultimately fail is that you might call a procedure in a SELECT that actually mutates something. There's pretty much no way to catch that. Note that [not all operations are transactional in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cannot-roll-back.html), so you might be surprised...

Comment: ...and [DDL in MySQL implicitly commits](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/transactions-notes-on-ddl-and-normal-transaction.html), or in other words ends your read only transaction.

Comment: Yes, I notice about that, thank you for your reminding! I should check whether it contains DML only or not at first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `SELECT` queries are all you need, you can create a control flow to stop execution/raise an error if a query performs any other action. There's a couple of alternatives to do this:

1 - Use regex to extract the first word of the query. Example:

```py
import re

def is_read_only_query(sql_query: str) -> bool:
    # Assumes a single query is defined in sql_query
    match = re.search(r"^\W*([\w-]+)", sql_query)
    return match.group(0).strip().lower() == "select" if match else False

if not is_read_only_query(sql_query):
   # Do something, e.g. raise Exception
```

2 - Use the method [`get_type()`](https://sqlparse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/analyzing/?highlight=type#sqlparse.sql.Statement) from the Python Package [sqlparse](https://pypi.org/project/sqlparse/). Example:

```py
import re
import sqlparse

def is_read_only_query(sql_query: str) -> bool:
    # Assumes a single query is defined in sql_query
    query_type = sqlparse.parse(sql_query)[0].get_type().lower()
    return True if query_type == "select" else False

if not is_read_only_query(sql_query):
   # Do something, e.g. raise Exception
```